# Add element in double[,] array

Tags: c#

I try to add element to `double[,]` array. But there was occured some issues with it. I must save coordinates in JSON. It looks like this:

```
{
  "Polyline": [
  {
    "name": "Line1",
    "towers": [
       [13.32, 33.12],
       [3.7, 565.5432],
       [867.762, 653.1676],
            ...
    ]
  ]
  }
}
```

and here is the code:

```
public double[,] GetTowersById(List<Towers> towers)
    {
        double[,] towersCoords = new double[towers.Count-1, towers.Count-1];

        using (ZadiagDBEntities context = new ZadiagDBEntities())
        {
            //List<Towers> tower = new List<Towers>();
            foreach (var item in towers)
            {
                int counter = 0;
                var tower = context.Towers.First(t => t.ID == item.ID);     // it is an object like Tower tower = new Tower(); with properties tower.Lat and tower.Long (their type is double)
                object currentElem = new double[]{ Convert.ToDouble(tower.Lat), Convert.ToDouble(tower.Long) };
                towersCoords.SetValue(currentElem, counter, counter);
                counter++;
            }
            //tower = context.Towers.Where(t => t.ID == towers[i].ID).ToList();


            }
```

The error message:

> Array is not single dimensional

Comment: "some issues" ?

Comment: What type of object is towersCoords?

Comment: too less information...

Comment: What is the definition of SetValue? Where is `towerCoords` defined? what is the type of `tower.Lat` and `tower.Long`?

Comment: I edited relating to your comments, i think it is clear now.

Comment: Could not understand what exactly is the problem. Please add more explanation/code to make people here understand.

Comment: What is not understandable??? Here it try to append values tower.Lat and tower.Long in multidimensional double array. That's it! But there is error: "Array is not single dimensional".

Comment: @LifanSolano have patience. You did not provide enough information while posted the question. But no problem, now you can add. Like this error message you posted in last comment. It should be posted along with original question in the very first attempt. And at which line you are getting this message will also help people here to understand better. Only when we can understand then we can have some suggestion for solution.

Comment: The size of your array is too small. Why `towers.Count-1`. By the way, professional programmer usually put spaces between operator like that: `towers.Count - 1`. This is far more readable.

Comment: Thank you, but i am not a professional programmer.

Comment: You are here to learn from professionals, aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

The problem your code have. 
`towersCoords` is 2D array of type `double`

```
double[,] towersCoords = new double[towers.Count-1, towers.Count-1];
```

And inside the loop you are adding/assigning this object(`currentEle`of type `array`) to the `towersCoords`

```
object currentElem = new double[]{ Convert.ToDouble(tower.Lat), Convert.ToDouble(tower.Long) };

towersCoords.SetValue(currentElem, counter, counter);
```

Which is wrong. Since it is an array of type `double`, it can't accept object of type `array`

It can accept items like:

```
towersCoords.SetValue(5, counter, counter);
```

Or else if you need to put `array` inside this 2D array, you have to change its type.

**Suggested Solution:**

Here is how you can do it other way. Since `currentElem` is only contains Lat and Long so for me it seems to be better suited as custom Struct object. 
Create a temp Struct.

```
struct TowerCoordiantes
{
    public double Lat;
    public double Long;

    public TowerCoordiantes(double pLat, double pLong)
    {
        this.Lat = pLat;
        this.Long = pLong;
    }
}
```

And type of `towersCoords` will become this:

```
TowerCoordiantes[,] towersCoords = new TowerCoordiantes[towers.Count-1, towers.Count-1];
```

And definition of currentElem with also change:

```
TowerCoordiantes currentElem = new TowerCoordiantes(Convert.ToDouble(tower.Lat), Convert.ToDouble(tower.Long));
```

And then this line will work as expected.

```
towersCoords.SetValue(currentElem, counter, counter);
```